# How to work with machine learning with data driven decision making?

Tags: workflows, machine-learning, decision-making

Not sure whether this is a fitting place to ask such a question, but here goes...

I learned about simple machine learning and supervised/unsupervised training back in Uni, where I specialized in machine learning, but haven't been able to utilize/practice that in my day-to-day work - which I am trying to do now.

What I seem to struggle with is understanding how one is supposed to work iteratively/logically when training a model and trying to apply it.

Today I tried to train an object detection model which couldn't detect anything and had 0% accuracy after a day of labeling data and an hour of model training (using the ml.net wizard).

My current theory is that my training failed due to not having enough data. But how do I prove my thesis without (any data) having to spend another day labeling data, another hour (or more) training, to either prove or disprove my theory?

If a similar problem arose with a software solution, my approach would be to try to confirm my theory with a formal test/proof of concept (POC) to then confirm that what I observe is due to either A or B. It may take a while to set up a scenario to confirm/disprove my theory, but at least there's a logical approach to things, and one is not bound to go with a solution 100%, only to realize it wasn't the right decision.

How is the iterative process in machine learning?

Answer (score 2):

An iterative pattern I've had lots of success with is:

1. Make the simplest possible thing work
2. Complicate it until it fails
3. Simplify until it works again
4. Repeat 2 and 3 to explore the models capabilities and limitations
5. Insist that these tests are fast

Waiting a day for results is just not a good idea. Simplify what you're asking for until you can get useful results in a timely manor and the results will point you in a useful direction sooner. Yes it will mean more work planning your training and different training sets. But you asked for iterative. Iterative is quick tiny steps. Not a Hail Mary.

Comment: I appreciate the approach, aligning well with how I handle regular coding tasks. The challenge? The ml.net wizard. It's a bit of a blind journey until issues pop up—no instincts kicking in. Noticing a periodic database glitch prompts an investigation, but here, there's no intuitive sense guiding me. Relying on experience and error logs helps catch dropped connections. What bothers me? A wizard claiming AI prowess should quickly spot glitches. Its simplicity suggests ease, but shouldn't it promptly highlight issues mid-training, asking, "No progress, do you want to continue?"

Comment: Prompt? No you should be continually watching results. When you decide continuing is pointless break out of the current process(es).

Comment: Here’s an [example](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=EWjUY_3ubf4) of watching AI results as they happen.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't disclose anything about the underlying
generative process IRL (the business domain),
nor what you observed from that process,
nor the model you chose.

We believe there is *structure* to the underlying generative process.
Why?
Because you chose to use ML techniques to predict its output Y.

It's unclear whether the observed features are *informative* features.
It's unclear whether noise in the training data is swamping the
signal Y.
It's unclear whether the model you chose is appropriate
for the underlying generative process.
(For example, an
[OLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares)
linear model would be inappropriate
for modeling "elapsed drop time" of objects falling to earth
from diverse heights, since a
[quadratic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_fall#Uniform_gravitational_field_without_air_resistance)
relationship can well explain observations of such processes.)

In summary there is a process in real life, we observe it,
create a model, and the model has poor predictive power.
We're unsure what went wrong.

## generate data

The standard approach to dealing with such uncertainties
is to **create your own ground truth**.

That is, you believe the generative process has structure,
which your chosen model captures (or captures "enough" of it).
There are parameters to be learned, such as {slope, intercept} in OLS.
Observations suffer from additive noise,
which we *hope* is stationary and has zero mean.
It is challenging to know if these modeling assumptions obtain IRL.

However, we have an opportunity to **generate** noisy data
based on known parameters. We know them, because we made them up.
And then we deliberately blind the model, we don't tell the
model about them, forcing it to learn those parameters
from the generated data.

This lets us validate that

- the model (e.g. "linear") seems appropriate because the generated data resembles real world observations, and
- the ML technique (e.g. "OLS") is demonstrably appropriate because it recovers learned parameters with acceptable deviation from Ground Truth values.

If there's a random distribution in the process,
maybe Gaussian, then we can crank up
[sigma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Standard_normal_distribution)
to gauge how insensitive our chosen technique is to noise.
Increase the noise until the technique breaks.
Then measure the real world process to verify
that it injects a suitably small amount of noise.

All of this will guide us as we refine
our model and our techniques for recovering its parameters.